# Get text of css element selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to use selenium to access the text of a css element.

```
WebElement test = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.CLFSBTextWithLink"));
System.out.println(test.getText());
```

This is what I'm doing right now but the output is empty.

For example the there might be a link or text on a website called "Company" and when I use Selenium to check where the element is, it says that the target is css=div.CLFSBTextWithLink. Now I want to be able to get the value "Company" somehow.

Comment: What output do you expect? It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: For example the there might be a link or text on a website called "Company" and when I use Selenium to check where the element is, it says that the target is css=div.CLFSBTextWithLink. Now I want to be able to get the value "Company" somehow.

Comment: This should absolutely work. Make sure there is only a single element on the page that is matched by "div.CLFSBTextWithLink". If there more of them, you must either change your selector, or loop over them all. If you could show us a relevant part of the HTMl around your element, we could possibly suggest a correct selection strategy.

Comment: If you go to http://viewer.opencalais.com/ and type something like "There was a man named Bob Bob" and hit submit, then you see under the entity person the name Bob Bob. I'm trying to get that name "Bob Bob" basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you go to [`http://viewer.opencalais.com/`](http://viewer.opencalais.com/) and type something like "There was
>   a man named Bob Bob" and hit submit, then you see under the entity
>   person the name Bob Bob. I'm trying to get that name "Bob Bob"
>   basically.

---

From the [`getText()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText%28%29) docs:

> Get the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) innerText of this element

But the text is initially hidden. You must first expand the Person element to make it visible. In this particular "Bob Bob" case, you can use:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("toggleVisibilityImage1")).click();
```

But always make sure you're clicking the right expander. To make it more general, this selects the expander next to the "Person" category:

```
//input[@class='collapseExpandIcon' and (../text()='Person')]
```

and explanation:

```
SELECT AN <input> ELEMENT
//input[                                                    ]
        THAT IS AN EXPANDER
        @class='collapseExpandIcon'
                                    AND ITS PARENT NODE HAS TEXT "Person"
                                    and (../text()='Person')
```